# Reverse Y axis using jQuery.flot

Tags: jquery, flot

I'm using jQuery.flot to create custom charts in my project, but I need invert the order of Y axis. Now, at the botton is the min value and at top de max value, I need to have the max value at botton and the min value at top.

This is my example: http://pastehtml.com/view/1doilsa.html

But the inverseTransform option seems not to work.

```
<body>
    script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"
    script type="text/javascript" src="http://flot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.flot.js"

    <div class="plot-lines" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $.plot($('.plot-lines'),
        [{
            data: [ [0, null], [1, 3], [2, 6], [3, 2], [4, null] ],
            lines: {
                show: true
            },
            points: {
                show: true
            }
        }],
        {
            xaxis: {
                ticks:  [ [0, ''], [1, 'Race 1'], [2, 'Race 2'], [3, 'Race 3'], [4, ''] ]
            },
            yaxis: {
                tickDecimals: 0,
                inverseTransform: function (v) { return -v; }
            }
        }
    );
    </script>
</body>
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not supported well in flot 0.6 (the current release).

There is hope though, if you are willing to use the development release (http://code.google.com/p/flot/source/checkout):

[Issue #263](http://code.google.com/p/flot/issues/detail?id=263) specifically was about that, and it is fixed in [r303](http://code.google.com/p/flot/source/detail?r=303)

Your best bet is just to check out the newest source and watch it work!

Comment: v0.7 of flot just got released, so you could update to that and have something well supported for the next good while!